# Postgres Rails App Setup on Mac not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Im using Mac on High Sierra 10.13.6

I try to Setup a Rails Application to run locally on my Mac. When i try to setup the Database with 'createdb xyz' and 'bin/setup', i get an error message:

Database 'xyz' does not exist
FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist

Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "template"=>"template0", "host"=>"localhost", "username"=>"postgres", "password"=>"postgres", "database"=>"xyz"}
rails aborted!

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to create a postgres user for your rails app. You can do that  by switching in to postgres user by following command.

```
> sudo su postgres
> psql
```

Then create an user:

`> create role role_name with createdb login password 'password';`

then exit `> \q` `> exit`

Replace the username & password in `config/database.yml` file with the credentials you created in postgres and then run `bin/setup`

For further reference you can follow this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-ruby-on-rails-with-postgres)

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Postgres using homebrew, it probably was created a SUPERUSER using your operating system (OS) USER, like your name. If you need a Postgres user, you must create using these commands:

```
dedeco@MacBook-Pro-Dedeco> psql postgres                                                                                                              
psql (12.2)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 dedeco    | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}

postgres=# CREATE USER postgres SUPERUSER;
CREATE ROLE
postgres=#
```